# Hide products that have an Empty Price from Woocommerce Archive / Shop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying hide products from on the frontend that have an empty price/a price wasn't set at all.

I found this code on here, but but it took extremely long for my site to load on all pages after adding it:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'shop_only_instock_products', 10, 2 );
function shop_only_instock_products( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // In frontend only
    if( is_admin() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query['relation'] = 'OR';

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_price',
        'value'   => '',
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '!='
    );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_price',
        'value'   => 0,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '!='
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
```

There was a code below it that was simpler, but it hid products that had the price/value of 0/zero,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'shop_only_instock_products', 10, 2 );
function shop_only_instock_products( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // In frontend only
    if( is_admin() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_price',
        'value'   => 0,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '>'
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
```

I rewrote it using values from the first code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'shop_only_instock_products', 10, 2 );
function shop_only_instock_products( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // In frontend only
    if( is_admin() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query[] = array(
       'key'     => '_price',
        'value'   => '',
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '!='
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
```

It worked, but unfortunately even though the pages loaded faster with the this code, it still took like 8-9 seconds to load a page, almost as if it was doing the calculation first before displaying the page after it got the results.

My question is are there any other ways to write the code, or are there any other code options that simply hide products without a price on Archive/Shop Frontend pages? (That doesn't cause much of a load?) Even if the method is through Javascript and CSS, for example locking in on a product that doesn't have a price set, and hiding it

Comment: how many products you have? that meta query shouldn't have cause that long query time unless you have lots of junks in your `postmeta` table, try installing this and see which hook/query is taking that long https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Comment: I have close to 20,000 products. The person who I saw these codes from as well said they made his site take a very long time to load. I'll check the postmeta, but I think the more products you have the longer this type of code will take